# How to identify browser supports j-query chunk upload plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am developing a web application for mobile where I am using jquery file up-loader plugin. [from here](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

it works great on mobile Chrome and Mozilla. But don't work on default android browser. I want to hide the input where it does not support the plugin. I tried Google, no luck. Can anyone tell how to identify chunk support for the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
if(jQuery.fileupload())
{ 
    //hide input code here 
}
```